# Assign multiple values in range

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In VBA I can assign array to range of cells, so that every cell in range gets corresponding value from the array:

```
Range("A1:D1").Value = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I was trying to do the same with openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.range['A1:D1'].value = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but without success.

Is there a way to do range assignment with openpyxl without iterating every cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, a range in openpyxl is just a range of cells but looping is easy enough (openpyxl 1.8 syntax)

```
for v,c in zip([1, 2, 3, 4], ws['A1':'D1']):
     c.value = v
```

Comment: Is this still the suggested syntax (using 2.3-2.4)?

Comment: Yes: 1.8 introduced the ability to use a slice to get a range of cells. The `range` method was deprecated.